# Getting permission denied for /bin/sh to start Go server in production | docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, go, permissions, docker-compose

I'm running `sudo docker-compose` on my production server to start up my Go container. I have sudo access in my production server but am not the root user.

error:

```
go_1     | /bin/sh: ./: Permission denied
```

docker-compose.yml

```
go:
    build:
      context: ./api
      args:
        app_env: ${APP_ENV}
    volumes:
      - ./api:/go/src/myproject/api
    expose:
      - "8080"
```

Go Dockerfile

```
From golang:1.8.3-alpine3.6

RUN apk update && \
    apk add \
        bash \
        build-base \
        curl \
        make \
        git \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ARG app_env
ENV APP_ENV $app_env

COPY . /go/src/myproject/api
WORKDIR /go/src/myproject/api


CMD if [ ${APP_ENV} = prod ]; \
    then \
    ./; \
    else \
    go get github.com/pilu/fresh && \
    fresh; \
    fi


EXPOSE 8080
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: You can't execute a directory `./`. What is it you want that to do?

Comment: build the go directory

Comment: was trying to follow this tutorial https://medium.com/statuscode/golang-docker-for-development-and-production-ce3ad4e69673

Comment: Why would you assume `./;` builds go? Nothing like that in the linked article, they build go on line 10 https://gist.github.com/McMenemy/485659e9e691c4a37976473a6d275f46#file-dockerfile-L10.

Comment: oh i meant serve the go binary

Comment: instead of `./` use the name of the binary that resulted from the `RUN go build`, just like they use `app` in the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your go program and then tell Docker, with `CMD`, to use the resulting binary as the default executable.

Try something like this:

```
From golang:1.8.3-alpine3.6

RUN apk update && \
    apk add \
        bash \
        build-base \
        curl \
        make \
        git \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ARG app_env
ENV APP_ENV $app_env

COPY . /go/src/myproject/api
WORKDIR /go/src/myproject/api

RUN go get ./
RUN go build

CMD if [ ${APP_ENV} = prod ]; \
    then \
    api; \
    else \
    go get github.com/pilu/fresh && \
    fresh; \
    fi


EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't named the package containing the main function as "main", I found with multi-stage builds it was building but it wasn't a binary.

There was no obvious error message.

Make sure your go code builds and runs on your host, before containerising it.